# slider dinamico con php y bootstrap

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4

tengo el siguiente problema: quiero realizar un slider dinamico pero no lo pedo generar, no se mueve y el div se sale de pantalla:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
          <?php include('slider.php');?>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
          <?php echo $slider_html; ?>
          </div>
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
          </a>
          </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
            </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

el codigo que uso en php:

```
<?php
include_once("inc.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM juegos LIMIT 4";
$resultset = mysqli_query($cnx, $sql) or die("database error:". 
mysqli_error($cnx));
$image_count = 0;
$button_html = '';
$slider_html = '';
while( $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset)){
$active_class = "";
  if(!$image_count) {
    $active_class = 'active';
    $image_count = 1;
  }
  $image_count++;
  $thumb_image = "nature_thumb_".$rows['nombre'];

  $slider_html.= "<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 bg-juegos 
  rounded mt-2 pt-4 ".$active_class."'>";
  $slider_html.= "<div class='col-md-12 w-100 block'>";
  $slider_html.= "<a href=juegos.php?id=".$c['id']."><img 
  src='../img/juegos-ps3/".$rows['img']."' alt=".$rows['nombre']."'.jpg' 
  class='juegos rounded'></a>";
  $slider_html.= "</div>
                  <div class='col-md-12 mt-1'>
                    <a href=juegos.php?id=".$c['id']."><h4>".$c['nombre']." 
                    </h4></a>
                    <p>Plataforma: ".$c['plataforma']."</p>
                    <p>Precio: $".$c['precio']."</p>
                  </div>
        </div>";

  $button_html.= "<li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='".$image_count."' class='".$active_class."'></li>";
}
?>
```

con esto genero el slider pero me lo hace sobresalir de pantalla y me los deja grande como que si no tomara algunos estilos.

yo lo que quiero es que queden los divs asi, de este tañano, pero en una sola linea con el movimiento que lleva un slder:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me queda asi, una debajo de la otra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y al usar el inspector de chrome el

```
<div class='col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 bg-juegos rounded mt-2 pt-4 ".$active_class."'>
```

me aparece a lo largo de toda la pagina.
alguna idea???

Comment: ¿Qué versión de bootstrap estas usando?

Comment: @Orici usa la v4. Ricardo, por defecto, Bootstrap solo muestra 1 item (imagen) por cada _slide_, si deseas que se vean varios items en pantalla, puedes mirar [estos ejemplos] y adaptarlos a tu código o usar una libreria que te ayude con eso, p ej. Owl Carousel es muy popular, [échale un vistazo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)

Comment: la version 4 orici

Comment: @RicardoMartinLeguizamon en mi anterior comentario olvidé poner los enlace a los ejemplos, aquí te lo dejo https://codepen.io/pinglu/pen/GaxBPJ